# How to find set difference of two files?

Tags: bash, gnu-coreutils

I have two files A and B. I want to find all the lines in A that are not in B. What's the fastest way to do this in bash/using standard linux utilities? Here's what I tried so far:

```
for line in `cat file1`
 do
   if [ `grep -c "^$line$" file2` -eq 0]; then
   echo $line
   fi
 done
```

It works, but it's slow. Is there a faster way of doing this?

Comment: Can you possibly show some code or explain what you've tried? Your question as it stands makes it seem like you want us to do all the work for you. Oftentimes, showing code will help encourage more answers, and better results.

Comment: You should also define what you expect by "fastest". It is about processing time, or time spent writing the code. For the second, I would go for something like `diff A B | grep '^-'`

Comment: @jmort253, thanks, I edited the question to add more detail

Comment: There are some problems with your example outside of solving the actual problems. You shouldn't use for line in `cat file`, that does not iterate over lines, it iterates over words. The next is grep returns non-zero when there is no match, so use -q instead of -c and remove the test. Also, you example includes a syntax error. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: I'd say this probably belongs on superuser.com or unix.stackexchange.com, voting to move

Comment: @therefromhere - Maybe unix, but superuser? This is a programming question. Plus, it's getting answers here. My vote is that it's probably ok.

Comment: @jmort253 I suppose, since it's framed as a programming question - though you can answer it without resorting to programming.

Comment: @therefromhere how often is determining a set intersection an end-user task? It may happen on occasion, but it's much more frequently something that needs to happen in a programmatic context... and from where I stand, it's the target audience, rather than the means needed to find a solution, that determines the appropriate forum.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[The BashFAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ) [describes doing exactly this with comm](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/036), which is the canonically correct method.

```
# Subtraction of file1 from file2
# (i.e., only the lines unique to file2)
comm -13 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

diff is less appropriate for this task, as it tries to operate on blocks rather than individual lines; as such, the algorithms it has to use are more complex and less memory-efficient.

comm has been [part of the Single Unix Specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/comm.html) since SUS2 (1997).

Comment: Thats a handy program.  I haven't seen that one before.  I wonder what other little gems of shell applications that my past life as a sysadmin missed.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want lines that are in file `A`, but not in `B`, you can sort the files, and compare them with diff.

```
sort A > A.sorted
sort B > B.sorted
diff -u A.sorted B.sorted | grep '^-'
```

Comment: You don't need temp files for that. `diff <(sort A) <(sort B) | grep '^-'`

Comment: This is _very_ inefficient compared to using `comm`. `diff` tries to compute the shortest possible edit difference between your inputs and outputs, with an algorithm that does a bunch of extra work and has potentially nasty edge cases; `comm` never needs to store more than one line of input from each file in memory at a time, and its performance is basically O(n+m) with no backtracking or worst-case scenarios that can make it slower.

Answer (score 0):

The 'diff' program is standard unix program that looks at differences between files.

```
% cat A
a
b
c
d
% cat B
a
b
e
% diff A B
3,4c3
< c
< d
---
> e
```

With a simple grep and cut one can select the lines in A, not in B.  Note that the cut is rather simplistic and spaces in the lines would throw it off... but the concept is there.

```
% diff A B | grep '^<' | cut -f2 -d" "
c
d
```

Comment: `diff` is slow and memory-hungry compared to `comm`, as it's trying to compute the smallest possible edit difference. It's not the best tool for this job.